# How to perform smooth scrolling on IHTMLELEMENT control

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a webpage which I need to display in my desktop application (WPF). I am using WebBrowser control. The webpage which I am populating has an IHTMLELEMENT control which has scrolling and I need to perform the smooth scrolling.

I am able to get the IHTMLELEMENT control and perform scrolling using (IHTMLELEMENT).scrollIntoView(true) -> to scroll top and (IHTMLELEMENT).scrollIntoView(false) -> to scroll bottom. This perform scrolling in one shot and I want to perform scrolling smoothly and slowly.

Comment: Two things I'd consider for this requirement. 1) Use javascript and maybe inject it if necessary. 2) WebView and hence edge rather than ie. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview

Comment: @Parthasarthi B.K Do you want to scroll only the separate HTML element or the whole html document and window?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski : I want to scroll HTML Element.